# How do I only display a specific layout for Controller X

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

Let's say I only want to display a specific layout when I'm on the home page.
The home page's controller and action is `home#index`.

How do I display a different layout for `business#new`?

Answer (score 1):

There are couple of options:

### Option 1 - Specific Layout at Controller level

Just create a layout file named `business.html.erb` in `app/views/layouts` and it will be automatically picked for rendering ALL the views of `BusinessController`

### Option 2 - Custom layout name at Controller level

Create a layout file named `my_custom_name.html.erb` in `app/views/layouts`
and in your controller specify it as:

```
class BusinessController < ApplicationController
  layout "my_custom_name"
  #...
end
```

`my_custom_name` layout would be used for ALL the views corresponding to  `BusinessController`.

### Option 3 - Layout for a particular action in a Controller

Create a layout file named `layout_name.html.erb` in `app/views/layouts`
and in your controller specify it as:

```
class BusinessController < ApplicationController

   def new
     # ...
     render :layout => "layout_name"
   end 
end
```

In this case, `layout_name` layout would only be applied for rendering `new.html.erb` page.

Comment: Thanks for the response!

I forgot to mention that the reason I need the if state is because it's a menu in my `application.html.erb`. 

How would you suggest I solve this?

Comment: " I need the if state is because it's a menu in my application.html.erb" ?? Can you be more specific than that. Also, this is another question as my answer and user3515444's answer resolve your current question. I would suggest you to post another question with specific details of exactly what you are trying to achieve explaining your use-case.

Answer (score 0):

you can specify the layout of a controller with

```
class businessController < ApplicationController
  layout "business_layout"
  #...
end
```

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html 2.2.14 Finding Layouts

Comment: Thanks for the response!

I forgot to mention that the reason I need the if state is because it's a menu in my `application.html.erb`. 

How would you suggest I solve this?